# Set logfile location based on OS in spring boot application.properties/.yml

Tags: spring-boot, logging, application.properties

I'm wondering if there's a nice clean way to set logging location based on OS just using the application.properties file in Spring Boot?

For instance is it possible to use a regex matcher on ${os.name} or would I just need to go ahead and create a groovy script or something?

My ideal solution is something like

```
logging:
  file:  ${os.name}.test(/*window*/gi) ? C:/ProgramData/Logs/ : /var/log/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) and pick configurations according to the `-Dspring.profile.active=some_profile` system property or `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=some_profile` env variable.
Yaml file could be

```
# a safe default relative to app root
logging:
     file: logs 

----

spring:
    profiles: nix
logging:
     file: /var/log/myapp

----


spring:
    profiles: win
logging:
     file: C:/ProgramData/Logs/
```

App is executed as

```
java -Dspring.profile.active=nix <more opts> MyAppMain
```

or also:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=nix java <more opts> MyAppMAin
```

Comment: Thanks it's not exactly what I was hoping for but I used this in conjunction with a regex  in spring bootstrap to set additional profiles - app.setAdditionalProfiles("linux");